# Viewing decompiled code of an Android function in Frida

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm trying to use Frida (Android 7 device - rooted emulator) according to the JavaScript API.

This is the current code:

```
Java.perform(function() {
    var x = Java.use('com.x.myCustomClass.util')
    console.log(x.functionIKnowExists) // will return function n() { [ecmascript code] }
}
```

However, while accessing functions, I get this error:

```
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 12.6.12 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at http://www.frida.re/docs/home/
Attaching...
function n() { [ecmascript code] }
```

How can I view the actual implementation (decompiled code) of  of the function `"functionIKnowExists()"` instead?

Comment: AFAIK Frida and the functions you use are designed to hook methods, not to dump the (Java byte) code. If you want to decompile a method process the APK using apktool, Jadx or any other Android decompiler.

Comment: What can I do with hooks then?

Comment: Write your own code and replace the original function with it or execute your code before/after the method is called. You can also print (or change) variables at run-time.

Comment: How do I print variables in run time? if i may ask here

Comment: That depends on the concrete variable, the type...  Search here on SO or read the Frida documentation.

Comment: Read the entire javascript docs and nothing, any chance you can link me somewhere? i just want to print passed variables.

Comment: "Just printing" can be quite difficult. Anyway we are here in the comments. Hook the method you want to check the parameter of. Once you have a working example (see other Frida questions as example here on SO) create a new question with a concrete example and a concrete question including the parameter type!